CSS to align ul menu to the right inside flexbox
My codepen has a logo image on the left and ul menu on the right - after the menu finishes there is empty space to the right of the menu - how do I tell the menu to align to the right so that the empty space is to the left of the menu?
I have tried various things which have not worked such as


.flexbox-1-4 {
  border:2px solid red;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding:4px;
  justify-content:space-between; 
}

.left {
  flex:1;
   border:2px solid pink;
}
.right {
  flex:4;
  border:1px solid lime;
}

ul { 
  list-style:none;
  border:2px solid cyan;
  display:inline-block;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
padding-right:18px;
}
<div class="flexbox-1-4">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7d/Wikimedia-logo-200px-transparent.png" width=100px>
  </div>
   <div class="right">
 <ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
   <li>Water</li>
   <li>Orange</li>
</ul>
    </div>
   </div>




Just remove flex:1 and flex:4. The two items will then sit left and right.

What you need to do is something like this:


.flexbox-1-4 {
  border:2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 4px;
}

.left {
  border: 2px solid pink;
}

.right {
  flex: 1; /* Adjusted to occupy remaining space */
  border: 1px solid lime;
  display: flex; /* Added to align items inside .right */
  justify-content: flex-end; /* Align items to the right */
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid cyan;
  display: inline-block;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 18px;
}
<div class="flexbox-1-4">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7d/Wikimedia-logo-200px-transparent.png" width="100px">
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <ul>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
      <li>Water</li>
      <li>Orange</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>




That works thanks but I have always used flexbox with flex values for the children such as flex:2 or flex:4 etc so why does your .left have no flex: value? And is flex:1 doing anything for your .right ? I think the result is the same if I change .right to flex:100, or just remove flex:1 ?



No flex value for .left: The .left element doesn't need a flex value because it's only as wide as its content (the logo). It doesn't need to grow or shrink relative to other elements.


flex: 1 for .right: Setting flex: 1 on .right allows it to grow and fill the available space in the flex container. The actual number in flex: 1 is less important; what's crucial is that it allows .right to expand and take up any remaining space. Using flex: 100 or removing flex: 1 would have a similar effect because .right is the only element set to grow.



Remove inline-block from the ul element and use text-align: right


.flexbox-1-4 {
  border: 2px solid red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 4px;
}

.left {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid pink;
}

.right {
  flex: 4;
  border: 1px solid lime;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  border: 2px solid cyan;
  text-align: right;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-right: 18px;
}
<div class="flexbox-1-4">
  <div class="left">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/7d/Wikimedia-logo-200px-transparent.png" width=100px>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <ul>
      <li>Coffee</li>
      <li>Tea</li>
      <li>Milk</li>
      <li>Water</li>
      <li>Orange</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>



